# how can i transfer an object in select option html tags on react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have 2 state arrays :
1)songs - array that holds songs objects (example: [song1 , song2, song3]
2)playlist - an empty array

i'm trying to create a select/option form, when i push "add to playlist" button,
the playlist array will hold the element from songs and delete the element from songs array
example after push (song1):
1)songs - [song2, song3]
2)playlist - [song1]

when i push the first element its working but all the other elements its not working.

code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import detect from 'bpm-detective';

import SongsList from './components/SongsList';
import SongDetails from './components/SongDetails';

class App extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);



        this.state = {
            currentSongChanged: false,
            currentSongDuration: 0,
            currentSongId: 'fmaFNKY-01',
            playlist: [],
            currentSongNewPlay: true,
            currentSongPlaying: false,
            isPlayAll: false,
            isPlayAllChild: false,
            currentSongTime: 0,
            keepSongPlaybackSetting: false,
            selectedSongId: 'fmaFNKY-01',
            songs: this.props.songs,
            bpm: 0,
            selectValue: this.props.songs[0]
        };

        // Bindings
        this.toggleCurrentSong = this.toggleCurrentSong.bind(this);
        this.playAll = this.playAll.bind(this);
        this.bpmCalculator = this.bpmCalculator.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);


        /*
            this.playAll = this.playAll.bind(this);
        */
    }







    // flag component change to display details of specified song id
    playAll() {
        if (this.state.isPlayAll) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.props.songs.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.props.songs[i].id).loop = false;
                document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.props.songs[i].id).pause();
                document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.props.songs[i].id).currentTime = 0;
            }
            this.setState({
                isPlayAll: false
            });
        }
        else {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.props.songs.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.props.songs[i].id).loop = true;
                document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.props.songs[i].id).play();
            }
            this.setState({
                isPlayAll: true
            });
        }
    }

    /*            for (let i = 0; i < this.props.songs.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("currentAudio" + this.props.songs[i].id).play();
                }
                this.setState({
                    isPlayAll: true
                })*/

 
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({selectValue: event.target.selectValue});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert(this.state.selectValue.title);
        var tempPlaylist = this.state.playlist.slice();
        tempPlaylist.push(this.state.selectValue);

        /*var tempSongs = this.state.songs.slice();
        tempSongs.remove(this.state.selectValue);*/
        this.setState({
             playlist:tempPlaylist,
             /*songs: tempSongs*/
        });
        event.preventDefault();
           
       


        }



    

    render() {

        // get data of current song, including current index position in song list array
        let currentSong;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.songs.length; i++) {
            if (this.props.songs[i].id === this.state.currentSongId) {
                currentSong = this.props.songs[i];
                currentSong.index = i;
            }
        }

      

        // toggle between play/pause button
        let playBtn = "button__play";
        if (this.state.isPlayAll) {
            playBtn = "button__pause";
        }

        let songList = this.state.songs;
        let optionItems = songList.map((song) =>
            <option value={song.title} key={song.title}>{song.title}</option>
        );

        let playlistList = this.state.playlist;
        let optionItems2 = playlistList.map((song) =>
            <option value={song.title} key={song.title}>{song.title}</option>
        );


        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="title-bar">
                    <img className="logo" src="/Cloud.png" alt=""/>
                    <h1> Musico - Looper </h1>
                    <h2>{this.bpmCalculator("upstep.mp3")}</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="playlist">
                            <div className="playlist__title">
                                <select>
                                    {optionItems2}
                                </select>
                                <h1> Featured Playlist List: </h1>
                                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <label>
                                <select value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                    {optionItems}
                                </select>
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Add to Playlist"/>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div className="playlist__content">
                                {this.props.songs.map((song) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Route exact path="/"
                                               render={() => <SongsList bb = {3} bpmNum = {this.bpmCalculator(song.src)} playAll={this.state.isPlayAll} songs={song}
                                                                        currentSongId={this.state.currentSongId}/>}/>
                                    );
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {/*<Route exact path="/" render={()=><SongsList songs={ this.state.songs } btnHandler={ this.toggleCurrentSong } linkHandler={ this.showSongDetails } currentSongId={ this.state.currentSongId } />}/>
              <Route path="/:songId" render={(props)=><SongDetails song={ this.state.songs.find((song)=>song.id === props.match.params.songId) } playSong={ this.selectCurrentSong }  downloadSong={ this.incrementDownloadCount } starSong={ this.starSong }/>}/>*/}
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="footer">
                            <div className="media-player">
                                {/*<audio id="currentAudio" src={ "/audio/" + currentSong.source } onDurationChange={ this.setCurrentSongDuration } onTimeUpdate={ this.setCurrentSongTime }></audio>*/}
                                {/*                <div className="media-player__text">
                  <span className="media-player__text--left"> Now playing: { currentSong.title } </span>
                  <span className="media-player__text--right"> { moment( this.state.currentSongTime * 1000 ).format('m:ss') } / { moment( this.state.currentSongDuration * 1000 ).format('m:ss') } </span>
                </div> */}
                                <div className="media-player__controls">
{/*                                    <div className="button__previous" onClick={() => {
                                        this.selectCurrentSong(previousSong.id, keepPlayBackSetting)
                                    }}></div>*/}
                                    <div className={playBtn} onClick={this.playAll}></div>
{/*                                    <div className="button__next" onClick={() => {
                                        this.selectCurrentSong(nextSong.id, keepPlayBackSetting)
                                    }}></div>*/}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is `Array.remove` actually an existing function?

Comment: no, i just wanted to show what i meant. i deleted that when i ran the code. the push also doesn't work properly

Comment: "... but all the other elements its not working."  So what is happening? What value if any is there for subsequent event handlers execution? What debugging results do you see?

Comment: "I deleted that when I ran the code". How can we help you if the code you ask us to examine is not the actual code you ran?

Comment: you are right with everything you are saying. i'll try to explain:
what is happens is that only if i push once the button , the element added to the playlist state, but after the second push nothing happens.
i will delete the "remove" function.
thanks.

Comment: My snap sense is that song lists/ play lists `state` changes are out of synch because they are spread out amongst different event handlers as well as  a mix of `this.props` and `this.state` usage. So I think it will be a long term headache as your code continues to evolve.

Comment: Please add what troubleshooting you did and the explanation of what's happening to your question. Buried in comments makes it too hard to find and too easy to miss.

Comment: Go to the help center - the question mark icon in the upper right of this screen - and read about how to ask a question well. [A link to `HelpCenter>Asking`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)